# Not a registered tag library - Django custom filter error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings

I added a new custom template filter for my django app but I get the error

```
'my_filters' is not a registered tag library. 
Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
compress
i18n
js
keyvalue
l10n
log
mul
rest_framework
static
staticfiles
tz
```

I added my_filters.py in templatetags directory in the app directory. It also contains the '__ init __.py'file
this is my_filters

```
from django.template import Library
register = Library()
@register.filter(is_safe=True, name='lookup')
def lookup(dict, index):
    if index in dict:
        return dict[index]
    return ''
```

my template file looks like

```
{% block content %}
    {% load my_filters %}
    {% load mul %}

    {% if not all_facilities %}
        <div class="panel-warning pane
```

This loads fine and works properly in my local machine when i run form pycharm. But the error is when i pushed it to production. I even restarted the server on production but i still get the error

Comment: The app must be in your settings.INSTALLED_APPS and the file that makes a directory a package is `__init__.py`, not "init.py". Also, make sure that you have no  ImportError if you try to directly import this module from the django shell.

Comment: The app called Webapp is indeed in the INSTALLED_APPS in settings file. and the init file is named correctly

Comment: Is the template the one you are actually rendering from your view or is it some base template that you extend?

Comment: @shmee its the template that i render, but it's extended from another base template. It's renders fine when i run it locally. I get the error in production server.

Comment: if the problem is only in one given environment then there's at least one thing that differs (in the settings, in files permissions, etc). Find what differs and you'll solve the problem.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers the settings files are exactly the same in both environments

Comment: somebody help.....I'm on the verge of a mental breakdown..

Comment: I didn't mean the problem was specifically with your settings  - that was just one example of what could differ, many other things have to be inspected.  You may also want to make sure you don't have any stalled .pyc files, that your `sys.path` is correct etc.

Comment: Actually the first thing I'd do would be to log on the production server via ssh, launch the django shell and try to import the templatetags module.

Comment: i already did that, it imports fine @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: @user6714507 how did you solve the problem ? I have exactly the same error as you, except that for me it doesn't even work in development